# shell scripting errors

Tags: shell, unix

As a part of my homework exercise, i am finding it difficult to execute the following two commands. Can you please rectify the error in it. Thanks in advance

> Write a program, that will take a file which has a set of directories, and will
>    look into these directories and their sub directories for any files named core.* 
>   and *.o and will print a report of all such files found.  (you can use find)

For the above program i attempted to do like this.

```
cat prog1 | xargs find /$0 -name 'core.*' or '*.o'
```

But I am getting the following error. (prog1 is a file containing list of directories)

```
find: paths must precede expression: perl
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

The next question is:

> Write a script that will go through the /etc/passwd file, and from this print a list of users in the system, their home directory and the shell that they are using

For which I tried the following:

```
awk '{print "USER \t\t HOME \t\t BASH \n split($0,a,":")}
     {print $a[1] \t\t $a[6] \t\t   $a[7]}' /etc/passwd
```

I tried googling and seeing the man entries but I don't understand the error. Also can you provide some useful links to shell scripting for beginners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Write a program, that will take a file which has a set of directories, and will
look into these directories and their sub directories for any files named core.*
and *.o and will print a report of all such files found.  (you can use find)
```

I suggest following oneliner:

```
find `paste -s -d' ' directories.list` -type f -name 'core.*' -or -name '*.o'
```

Where `directories.list` contains directories names, one by line.

```
Write a script that will go through the /etc/passwd file, and from this print a
list of users in the system, their home directory and the shell that they are
using
```

Try this:

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN{print "USER\t\tHOME\t\tSHELL"}{printf("%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\n", $1, $6, $7)}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: thank you :) it worked.Pls can you tell me what was the error in my approach

Comment: @chid 1) When `xargs` invoke `find` it adds your path to end of command, but `find` expected it before expressions 2) (as @ignacio-vazquez-abrams already said) `find` doesn't have `or` option (use `-or` or `-o` instead)

Comment: "adds your path to the end of command" - can you please explain this part?

Comment: @chid when `xargs` build command to run it append lines from stdin to command which your specify. In result it executes command like following: `find / -name 'core.*' or '*.o' path1 path2 path3`
`

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: `find` does not understand "or". The *operator* follows the same pattern as the other options.

Hint 2: `awk` can use a custom delimiter/*field separator*.